# Acer TravelMate 220 doesn't resume 

Tags: 11.10, power-management, acer

My computer (Acer TravelMate 220) likes sleeping so much that I can't wake it up.  I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 (installed Nov 2011).  Based on similar questions posted, it seems to have been an issue in the past, but not so much now.  I'm open to any advice.  Worse case, I can deactivate the sleep modes.  We just like running the laptop all day for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is relevant, but is your swap partition at least as big as the amount of memory in the notebook? When Linux hibernates it uses the swap partition to write out the contents of RAM.